# Json array elements duplication using jolt

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I want to know if jolt can handle the following transformation:

```
{
  "interface": [
    {
      "field": "A",
      "ip": [
        "1.1.1.1",
        "1.1.1.2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "field": "B",
      "ip": [
        "1.1.1.3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "interface": [
    {
      "field": "A",
      "ip": "1.1.1.1"
    },
    {
      "field": "A",
      "ip": "1.1.1.2"
    },
    {
      "field": "B",
      "ip": "1.1.1.3"
    }
  ]
}
```

i.e for a JSON array containing a child array, create one version of parent item for each of its child array item.

Can jolt do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing a two stage shift:

1. Create an array of arrays
2. Then flatten the array of arrays

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "interface": {
        "*": {
          "ip": {
            "*": {
              "@": "[&3].[&1].ip",
              "@(2,field)": "[&3].[&1].field"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "interface.[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not complete answer, but maybe that helps you somehow or someone else could help?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "interface": {
        "*": {
          "ip": {
            "*": {
              "@": "ip",
              "@(2,field)": "field"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ip": {
        "*": {
          "@": "interface[&1].ip",
          "@(2,field)": {
            "???": "interface[&2].field" // How to take proper index of an array?
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```